# How do I compare a value in one line to a value in another line?

Tags: python

I have a file that puts out lines that have two values each. I need to compare the second value in every line to make sure those values are not repeated more than once. I'm very new to coding so any help is appreciated.

My thinking was to turn each line into a list with two items each, and then I could compare the same position from a couple lists.

This is a sample of what my file contains:

```
20:19:18 -1.234567890
17:16:15 -1.098765432
14:13:12 -1.696969696
11:10:09 -1.696969696
08:07:06 -1.696969696
```

Here's the code I'm trying to use. Basically I want it to ignore those first two lines and print out the third line, since it gets repeated more than once:

```
with open('my_file') as txt:                                                                                           

   for line in txt: #this section turns the file into lists                                                                                                                              
       linelist = '%s' % (line)                                                                                                                   
       lista = linelist.split(' ')                                                                                                                

   n = 1                                                                                                                                          
   for line in lista:                                                                                                                             
       listn = line[n]                                                                                                                       
       listo = line[n + 1]                                                                                                                   
       listp = line[n + 2]                                                                                                                   
       if listn[1] == listo[1] and listn[1] == listp[1]:                                                                                                                   
           print line                                                                                                                             
       else:                                                                                                                                      
           pass                                                                                                                                   
       n += 1
```

What I want to see is:

```
14:13:12 -1.696969696
```

But I keep getting an error on the long `if` statement of "string index out of range"

Comment: I suspect that in lines 39-41 you'r not doing what you thing you're doing. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: You're overwriting `lista` each time through the first loop. When you go into the second loop, `lista` just contains the words in the last line of the file. You're never comparing between different lines.

Comment: @Barmar so do I just need to indent my second loop under the first?

Comment: No, you need to do some major redesign, because you don't understand the data structures you're creating.

Comment: @alfasin trying to set variables for line numbers. So if "listn" is line number 4, "listo" would be line number 5, and "listp" would be line number 6.

Answer (score 1):

You would be a lot better off using a dictionary type structure. Dictionary allows you to quickly check for existence.

Basically check if the 2nd value is a key in your dict. If a key then print the line. Else just add the 2nd value as a key for later.

```
myDict = {}
with open('/home/dmoraine/pylearn/%s' % (file)) as txt:
    for line in txt:
        key = line.split()[1]
        if key in myDict:
            print(line)
        else:
            myDict[key] = None #value doesn't matter
```

Answer (score 1):

Some simple debugging highlights the functional problem:

```
with open('my_file.txt') as txt:
   for line in txt: #this section turns the file into lists
       linelist = '%s' % (line)             
       lista = linelist.split(' ')          
       print(linelist, lista)

   n = 1                                    
   for line in lista:                       
       print("line", n, ":\t", line)
       listn = line[n]                 
       listo = line[n + 1]             
       listp = line[n + 2]             
       print(listn, '|',listo, '|',listp)
       if listn[1] == listo[1] and listn[1] == listp[1]:             
           print(line)                      
       n += 1
```

Output:

```
20:19:18 -1.234567890
 ['20:19:18', '-1.234567890\n']
17:16:15 -1.098765432
 ['17:16:15', '-1.098765432\n']
14:13:12 -1.696969696
 ['14:13:12', '-1.696969696\n']
11:10:09 -1.696969696
 ['11:10:09', '-1.696969696\n']
08:07:06 -1.696969696
 ['08:07:06', '-1.696969696\n']
line 1 :     08:07:06
8 | : | 0
```

In short, you've mis-handled the variables.  When you get to the second loop, `lista` is the "words" of the final line; you've read and discarded all of the others.  `line` iterates through these individual words.   Your listn/o/p variables are, therefore, individual characters.  Thus, there is no such thing as `listn[1]`, and you get an error.

Instead, you need to build some sort of list of the floating-point numbers.  For instance, using your top loop as a starting point:

```
float_list = {}
for line in txt: #this section turns the file into lists                                                                                       
    lista = line.split(' ')
    my_float = float(lista[1])         # Convert the second field into a float
    float_list.append(my_float)
```

Now you need to write code that will find duplicates in `float_list`.  Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up turning each line into a list, and then making a dictionary of all the lists. Thank you all for your help.